# What is JSFiddle using to resize the 4 code content areas?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

This question is about jsFiddle itself; specifically how the areas resize.

jsFiddle uses 4 independently resizable areas and they have a border between them with this graphic in the borders:

[image: Border resizing handle]

These resize handles cause the iframes to scroll if needed; its slick.  I've searched [jQueryUI Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/) thinking that was it.  Nope...

I really only know jQueryUI.  Is this a different library they are using to pull that off?  Can you identify and/or link me to what they are using to resize?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSFiddle uses [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) along with a layout plugin called [LayoutCM.js](http://code.google.com/p/raphael4gwt/source/browse/trunk/raphael4gwt/doc/raphaeltut/images/Edit+this+Fiddle+-+jsFiddle_files/LayoutCM.js?r=74). You could break apart the code to figure out how it's being handled but essentially the drag event is updating the panels width and height (percentage). A jQuery solution could be to use the [jQuery Splitter Plugin](http://methvin.com/splitter/).

Comment: the link to the jQuery splitter looks promising; I won't have to include / use another library for something minor.  At the risk of being edited again, thank you for the help, it is appreciated.